# Node.js Date does not consider DST (daylight saving time)

Tags: node.js, timezone, dst

I'm living in Vancouver, west coast of North America, Canada. The original timezone here is PST (pacific standard time, UTC - 8h), but it's now PDT (pacific daylight time, UTC - 7h) since the daylight saving time has started.

The problem is that Node.js uses the original non-DST time, while Ubuntu returns DST.

In the following, both should be 21:44.

```
$ echo `date` , `node -e "console.log(new Date().toString())"`
Mon May 25 21:44:57 DST 2020 , Mon May 25 2020 20:44:57 GMT-0800 (GMT-08:00)
```

Why does this happen? How to let Node.js recognize DST?

I use Noce.js v12.16.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 as WSL on Windows 10. (Node.js v12.16.3 for Windows works correctly.) `TZ` env is not set.

**UPDATE** I don't want to install external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

A more accurate library would be [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). You can set the time to recognize DST like this:

```
moment(timestamp).tz(timezone).isDST()
```

Here is an example:

```
moment(1451624400000).tz('America/New_York').isDST();
```

You can read more about recognized timestamps and timezones in the documentation on the website that I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

My test shows that node *does* honor daylight saving time:

```
$ date; node -e "console.log(new Date().toString())";
Fri Jul 17 23:13:32 EDT 2020
Fri Jul 17 2020 23:13:32 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

$ date --date='Fri Jul 17 2020 23:13:32 GMT-0400'
Fri Jul 17 23:13:32 EDT 2020

$ node -v
v10.21.0

$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```